# Talend Oracle Update taking more time

Tags: oracle11g, talend

I am having an ETL Process in talend to extract the data from SQL Server and Oracle compare those and then Insert the Transformed data in Oracle

The ETL process is

```
tSQLInput -- Row1 -----
                          -Comparison--TMap --->tOracleOutput
tOracleInput -- Row2 ---
```

The same process as above for insertion of 213058 rows it takes only 3 secs but for update it takes around 15 mins

For Insertion it takes 10000 rows/Sec, but same for update it takes 332 rows/sec

I want to increase this performance of update process

**tOracleOutput Basic Settings**

[image]

**tOracleOutput Adavnced Settings**

[image]

Can anybody please Shed some light on this issue why update alone is taking more time

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show your tOracleOutput settings ?

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar Added the Settings in the Question as an Update

Comment: Update performance depends on the data you have in the table. Insert will no perform any searching, in will just insert. But update will search the table and updates the records. Create required index, that will help you to increase the perfomance

Comment: @Jim Macaulay Thanks for Inputs I am trying to Update the column of the table which are referenced as Forigen key of other tables